# In search for easy counterexample of $L^2$ ineq. - if it exists

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

I want to find a function $u \in C^2([0, 3])$ such that
$$
\lVert u \rVert_{L^2([0, 3])} > 3\lVert u'' \rVert_{L^2([0, 3])}
$$
and $u(0) = u'(0) = 0$ - if it exists. I know that those functions fulfil
$$
\lVert u \rVert_{L^2([0, 3])} \leq \frac{9}{2} \lVert u'' \rVert_{L^2([0, 3])}
$$
which means that I am just unsure if this bound is sharp.
I also figured that observing monomials does not help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remember to use descriptive titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $u:[0,3]\to[0,1]$ by $u(x)=\sin(\frac{x}{2})$. Note $u''(x)^2=\frac{1}{16}\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$ and thus $u(0)=u''(0)=0$. Finally, $$\Vert u\Vert^2=\int_0^3\sin^2(x)\;dx=16\cdot\int_0^3\frac{1}{16}\sin^2(x)\;dx=16\cdot\Vert u''\Vert^2>0$$
$$\therefore\;\Vert u\Vert= 4\cdot\Vert u''\Vert>3\cdot\Vert u''\Vert$$
$$\therefore\;\Vert u\Vert= 4\cdot\Vert u''\Vert\leq\frac{9}{2}\cdot\Vert u''\Vert$$